# Overloading based on runtime type or avoiding if-else/switch-case

Tags: c#, .net, oop

My case is simple, I want to "map" exceptions to a HttpStatusCode. I could easily do this:

```
if (e is AuthenticationException)
{
    return HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
}
else
{
    return HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
}
```

I would then add more else-if blocks checking the types.

Is there a better way of doing this? I can't use overloads, because the compile-time type of `e` is `Exception`, even though the runtime type will be something else. So this won't work (basic .NET OO):

```
private static HttpStatusCode GetHttpStatusCode(Exception e)
{
    return HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
}

private static HttpStatusCode GetHttpStatusCode(AuthenticationException e)
{
    return HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
}
```

What would be an elegant way of coding this?

Answer (score 3):

Well, maybe you can add a few catch in your code, for example:

```
try{
    //code here
}
catch(AuthenticationException e){
    return HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
}
catch(InvalidOperationException e){
    return HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
}
catch(Exception e){
    return HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
}
```

And another exceptions that you need in your code.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't clear enough, for which I apologize. I'm getting the Exception object from Autofac in an IAutofacExceptionFilter, so I don't have a try-catch block.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a `Dictionary<Type, HttpStatusCode>` for the mapping:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Type, HttpStatusCode>
{
    { typeof(AuthenticationException), HttpStatusCode.Forbidden },
    // etc.
}

HttpStatusCode GetStatusCodeFromException(Exception e)
{
    HttpStatusCode code;
    if (!dict.TryGetValue(e.GetType(), out code))
        code = // Whatever default value you want
    return code;
}
```

Comment: This won't work for subtypes e.g. `class MoreSpecificException : AuthenticationException`.

Comment: @Lee That's not correct. It most certainly does work for subtypes.

Comment: `typeof(AuthenticationException).Equals(typeof(SubAuthenticationException))` is not guaranteed to return `true`, nor will they have the same hashcode, so the lookup will fail for subtypes even if a basetype is in the dictionary.

Comment: It "works" for subtypes in that it doesn't throw an exception, but it just returns the default value, which I wouldn't want. I guess I'll be using switch-case for the time being.